# How to edit a asp.net chart X Axis label and only show date and not time

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

[image]

How do I remove the time from the X Axis in my chart.
My sql returns date only but my code adds the time again.

I have tried:

`Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "##-##-##";`

But no luck.

My current code:

```
            Chart1.Visible = ddlChart.SelectedValue != "";
            string query = string.Format(stest);
            DataTable dt = GetData(query);
            string[] x = new string[dt.Rows.Count];
            int[] y = new int[dt.Rows.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                x[i] = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
                y[i] = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i][1]);
            }
            Chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(x, y);

            Chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar;
            Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;
            Chart1.Legends[0].Enabled = true;
```

**WORKING CODE** - Thanks jstreet

```
Chart1.Visible = ddlChart.SelectedValue != "";
            string query = string.Format(stest);
            DataTable dt = GetData(query);

            DateTime[] x = new DateTime [dt.Rows.Count];
            int[] y = new int[dt.Rows.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                x[i] = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[i][0]);
                y[i] = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i][1]);
            }
            Chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(x, y);

            Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "MM-dd-yyyy";

            Chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar;

            Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;

            Chart1.Legends[0].Enabled = true;
```

Comment: @jstreet If the orientation changes then the axis changes? So as you're saying in this horizontal bar graph, the X axis becomes the veritcal and the Y axis becomes the horizontal?

Comment: @MattB what orientation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a `Bar` chart (as opposed to a `Column` chart), the vertical axis is the `AxisX`, not `AxisY`. Also, avoid assigning a string to your `AxisX`. It is not necessary at all and may cause problems.

Use this:

```
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "MM-dd-yyyy";
```

or this:

```
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "MM-dd-yy";
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

Here's some sample code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime[] x = new DateTime[3];
        int[] y = new int[3];

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            x[i] = DateTime.Now.AddDays(i);
            y[i] = 10 * (i + 1);
        }
        Chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(x, y);
        Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "MM-dd-yy";
    }
```

Comment: Tried the above just after my `for` loop but no luck.

Comment: What data type is your table storing?

Comment: `DateTime.`." That's why you should not convert your DateTime to string" not sure what to do then in the for loop

Comment: Just assign a `DateTime` to your AxisX with no conversion to `string` whatsoever.

Comment: Please see my **EDIT**.

Answer (score 0):

The following below should work

```
 for (int i=0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
 {
     DataRow row = dt.Rows[i];
     x[i] = DateTime.ParseExact(row[0].ToString(), 'MM-dd-yy', CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
     y[i] = Convert.ToInt32(row[1]);
 }
```

Comment: Where Should I add the above code, surly not in the for loop because ther will be no definition for `ToShortDateString` ? And outside the `for` loop there is no context of `i`

Comment: @Ruan I would change them inside the for loop since that is where you are doing the original ToString() call.
My assumption is that the `dt.Rows[i][0]` is your DateTime value, correct?

Comment: `x[i] = dt.Rows[i][0].ToShortDateString("MM-dd-yy");` gives me an error of ` 'object' does not contain a definition for 'ToShortDateString' and no extension method 'ToShortDateString' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: I see my issue, You would need to get the row such as this
`DataRow row = dt.Rows[i]` then you would need to call the property by name and set it `row["DateProperty"] = (DateTime)row["DateProperty"].ToShortDateString("MM-dd-yy")`